Using the field header "x<23" in a function
I have a field [x<23].
I would like to use that field name in a function (e.g. Text.Split([x<23]," ").
I have tried entering each character of the field name as a unicode decimal using #() and Character.FromNumber only to return the error: "Invalid Identifier."
How to I enter the field name "x<23" (exclusive of quotations) into an M fuction?

Try
[#"x<23"] 

You can just add column ... custom column ... and choose your column and it would provide the code sample for the column name


Thanks, @horseyride! For some reason, everytime I come back to power query, I don't fail to forget that that syntax is not just for "step" names and tables.
